Pass primtive parameters Composable function by: Using counterProvider: () -> Int or Using counter:
In Jetpack Composable, I see someone pass primitive parameter by using counterProvider: () -> Int instead counter: Int
I don't understand the difference the using between two ways above.
Please someon explain for me. Thank u very much.
fun MyComposable(counter1: Int, counterProvider2: () -> Int) {
    Text("From MyComposable - Counter1 = ${counter1}", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5)
    Text("From MyComposable - Counter2 = ${counterProvider2()}", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5)
}


counterProvider2 is a function that returns an Int, not an Int itself. The handling isn't that different, but there is a significant difference in behavior. Both can be used to provide an Int value, but the value for counter1 is calculated before MyComposable is even called, where counterProvider2 just holds the function that calculates the value only when it is called inside of MyComposable.
The latter has two major advantages:

Maybe MyComposable doesn't always use the value. Especially when the calculation is expensive MyComposable can skip the calculation and save some CPU time.
Even if the calculation is simple the value may often change. When the value isn't always needed by MyComposable, not executing counterProvider2 saves an entire recomposition cycle. When the value changes a lot, this can noticeably improve UI performance.

But it also has disadvantages:

Setting up a function incurs an additional (small) cost that should be avoided when possible.
It's a bit harder to read due to the additional parentheses and braces.

Conclusion: There are good reasons for both variants. Usually the callee (in this case MyComposable) knows best. As a caller, don't think about it, just use it as it is.
When you write a composable and you are not sure if you should use a value or a function as parameter, use a value. Only when there is reasonable suspicion that at least one of the advantages lined out above could have a significant impact, think about switching the parameter to a function.

I have a little thinking, that is, whether if I use viewModel with MutableStateFlow instead using MutableState, if only using simply 1st variant as a value it will cause not rebuilt because of old value?
I have tried many experiment code, but none of them can demonstrate what I think above.
Please tell me whether I am true or false. Thank u.

You shouldn't pass State objects to a composable, only their value. You can wrap the State in a lambda as seen in counterProvider2, but otherwise only use State values to pass around. In addition, don't use MutableState in the view model. That introduces unexpected behavior in some edge cases. Use MutableStateFlow instead.

if I use viewModel with MutableStateFlow and in View I collectAsState and pass State value like 1st variant, whether it can cause any unexpected behaviors?

No, that's perfectly fine. That's what most of your code probably will look like.
